# Laravel groupby just like costum group by pipes

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, laravel-5, ionic3

i have a problem to foreach the key from group by laravel.

here is mycode :

```
$testing = \DB::table(\DB::raw($query))
        ->where('total.content_file_download','not like','% %')
        ->where('total.updated_at','!=','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
        ->orderBy('total.updated_at','desc')->paginate(10)
        ->groupBy('month')->map(function ($group) {
                          return ["data" => $group ];
                          });
```

and it return so well until i cant foreach the key

[image: the return]

how can i give an array name on the key so i can foreach them

i want to use foreach like:

```
<ion-grid *ngFor="let item of allgallery">
        <ion-item>{{item}}</ion-item>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col *ngFor="let element of item.data | slice:0:limit; let i=index">
<img [src]="'assets/img/no-img.jpg'" (click)="goView(element)"/>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

The result that i want is like:
[image: imageresult]

Comment: What do you mean you can't foreach on them? Can you share what you are currently doing?

Comment: okay ive edited my post. í want to group them and foreach like key and value. but in the laravel side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [mapWithKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-mapwithkeys) collection method instead of `map`?

Comment: Mapwithkey just like keyby()-> map(function($data) right? It will return only key. I already tried that.

Comment: No, in mapWithKeys you can return `key` and `value`.

```
$keyed = $collection->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item['email'] => $item['name']];
});
```

Comment: Okay i will try it. Thx for your answer luka :D

Comment: mapwithkey its not working for me. my array that i want is ini picture that ive been uploaded.